# Zoom na Imagem do Perfil Stack Overflow

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Estava consultando algumas perguntas e reparei que a foto de perfil de um usuário dava zoom ao passar o mouse em cima dela, porém com os demais usuários eu não notei esse comportamento, alguém sabe como esse usuário conseguiu tal resultado?

[Link da Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76394/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-pegar-url-atual-em-javascript)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que deve ser por causa da conexão do perfil com o linkedin, repare que quem tem o perfil "conectado" com o linkedin possui essa característica. Não tenho certeza mas acredito que deve ser isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto está disponível para todos usuários com pelo menos [1000 pontos obtidos no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), não precisa fazer nada a não ser obter essa reputação. É chamado User Card. Ele só aparece se tiver um mínimo de informação na descrição do usuário.

Comment: Rapaz que interessante, esse recurso é novo? Eu nunca tinha reparado nisso kkk.

Comment: Não, existe há muito tempo.

Comment: Falta de observação minha então kk

Comment: O Privilegio: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user - Todos privilégios: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Inclusive, há até uma tag especial para desativar isto quando você tem mais de 1000 pontos. Eu uso para evitar a "sombra" quadrada no meu avatar na lista de usuários, que é o indicador de que há um usercard ali.